# Using elixir in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

Is it possible to use elixir in lumen like in Laravel? 
I have tried by making package.json and gulpfile.js same as in Laravel, as suggested on one forum, but after running gulp I got the error:

> Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir'

Package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "laravel-elixir": "^5.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Gulpfile.js

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass('sass/app.scss', './public/css/app.css')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use Elixir with Lumen. Concerning the issue, it sounds like you need to run `npm install` from the root directory (containing your `package.json` file).